# volume calculation solving for $r:v=\pi r^3(2y-\frac23tanθ-\frac xr)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to be able to find the radius of a cone combined with a cylinder.
see my other question
(Solving for radius of a combined shape of a cone and a cylinder where the cone is base is concentric with the cylinder? part2 )

I have a volume calculation that Has been reduced as far as I know how to.

Know values:

$$v=65712.4$$
$$x=3$$
$$y=2$$
$$\theta=30$$
$$r=unknown$$

$$v=\pi r^3\left(2y-\frac{2}{3}\tan\theta-\frac{x}{r}\right)$$

Since I haven't solved a Quadratic equation in a while.

I would appreciate it explained in steps.

Thank You For Your Time.

Comment: Its a quartic equation in the variable $r$, I would simplify the equation by limiting the number of variables since you already know all of them but $r$. If you just want an approximate solution I would use a calculator. If you want an explicit solution in terms of radicals etc, I would look up quartic equation, and find a guide explaining how to solve them in general form.

Comment: Is that the volume given or is there an exact form of it? (perhaps involving $\pi$..)

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is Newton's method for approximation.

When I [type this into Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=v=pi*r%5E3%282*2-%282/3%29tan%2830%29-3/r%29%20solve%20for%20r), I get three nasty solutions, each that look something like this:

[image: one of the solutions]

Answer (score 1):

First we distribute the $\pi r^3$ in the parenthesis and subtract $v$ from both sides:

$0=\pi y r^3-\frac 23 \pi \tan \theta r^3 -\pi xr^2-v$  We factor out the $r^3$ in the first two terms only:

$0=r^3(\pi y - \frac 23 \pi \tan \theta) -xr^2-v$

Let's make $a=\pi y - \frac 23 \pi \tan \theta$ , $b=x$ and $d=v$ . So we have to find the solutions of the equation $0=ar^3-br^2-d$ . There is a formula for this called Cardano's formula, which can be found [here](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/). This will give you one solution. When you are done, you can divide your equation by $x-solution$ in order to get a quadratic equation, which can be solved by the quadratic formula. But this would take a very long time, so I just suggest to get a calculator to solve this, like anorton did in his answer.